# Insert TYPE_NUTRITION in Google Fit

Tags: google-fit

I get user input (calorie) and want to insert it in Google Fit but the insertion does not work.

```
private DataSet insertNutritionData(){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    DataSource nutritionSource = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName(getApplicationContext().getPackageName())
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_NUTRITION)
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .build();

    DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(nutritionSource);

    DataPoint dataPoint = DataPoint.create(nutritionSource);
    dataPoint.setTimestamp(endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
    dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_NUTRIENTS).setKeyValue(Field.NUTRIENT_CALORIES,calorie);                          

    dataSet.add(dataPoint);

    return dataSet;

}
```

The insertion is done in AsyncTask :

```
private class InsertAndVerifyNutritionTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        DataSet dataSet = insertNutritionData();

        Log.i(TAG, "Inserting the dataset in the History API");
        com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status insertStatus =
                Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(mClient, dataSet)
                        .await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        if (!insertStatus.isSuccess()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem inserting the dataset.");

            return null;
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Data insert was successful!");            

        return null;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the insertion is not done and I don't know why. There is no sample to explain how can we use TYPE_NUTRIENTS...

Thanks a lot !

[UPDATE]

I found this error :

```
Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
```

However, I build my client like this :

```
mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.RECORDING_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_NUTRITION_READ_WRITE))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(
                    new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Google Fit connected.");
                            mTryingToConnect = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "Notifying the UI that we're connected.");
                            notifyUiFitConnected();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                            // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
                            // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
                            mTryingToConnect = false;
                            if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                            } else if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                            }
                        }
                    }
            )
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(
                    new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                        // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"connection failed 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mTryingToConnect = false;
                            notifyUiFailedConnection(result);
                        }
                    }
            )
            .build();
}
```

Moreover, I don't understand why I cannot connect to fit whereas it worked perfectly...

Updated with the manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.webear.mysilhouette">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="mySilhouette"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<service
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name="com.example.webear.mysilhouette.GoogleApiIntentService"/>

(...)

</application>

</manifest>
```

Kamel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `statusCode` says [`API_UNAVAILABLE`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult#API_UNAVAILABLE). It means:

> One of the API components you attempted to connect to is not
>   available. The API will not work on this device, and updating Google
>   Play services will not likely solve the problem. Using the API on the
>   device should be avoided.

Maybe try another device? Or Play Services are misconfigured.